# How to custom web worker by angular-builder in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, web-worker, angular8, angular-builder

Use web worker in Angular 8 has a cross-domain problem when deploying on CDN(https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14901), so I want to use [angular-builder](https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/blob/master/packages/custom-webpack/README.md) to custom my worker. Angular cli use `worker-plugin`, and I use the `worker-loader` to export `inline` worker.

Here is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
const worker = new Worker('./app.worker.ts', { type: 'module' });

worker.onmessage = event => {
  console.log(`receive message ${event.data}`);
  worker.postMessage('Work done!');
};
```

**app.worker.ts**

```
const worker: Worker = self as any;
let i = 0;

function timedCount() {
  i = i + 1;
  setTimeout(timedCount, 500);
  worker.postMessage(`Hi ${i}`);
}
timedCount();
```

**angular.json**

```
// ...
"customWebpackConfig": {
  "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
}
```

**extra-webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.worker\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          },
          { 
            loader: 'worker-loader',
            options: {
              inline: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

But I get an error page when I run `ng serve`, how to configure this?

Comment: I've run into a similar (maybe the same) issue and written it up here at SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776443/how-do-i-resolve-resource-was-blocked-mime-type-mismatch-in-angular) and created a GitHub example.  Mine is based upon the simple example provided by the official Angular docs.

Comment: @raddevus I've seen your issue and mine is `cross-domain` error when deploying on CDN, not the same, thank you for your response.